# Programatically load a navigationController on tabitem click

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have made a UITabBarController where when selecting one of the item I load an imagepicker.Now after user chose an image from picker i want to load a navigation controller, which I'm not able to. My code is

```
extension BaseTabBarController : UITabBarControllerDelegate {

func  tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if self.viewControllers?.index(of:viewController) == 2 {
        // Presenting image picker here
        present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

 }

}
```

here's the code after user has picked image

```
extension BaseTabBarController : ImagePickerDelegate {

func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])  {

    //This is the StoryboardID of Navigationcontroller i want to goto
    let detailVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UploadNavigationController")
    //This is not working
    present(detailVC, animated: true,completion: nil)
 }
}
```

Here controller is not shown and I get this warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fb4969c4800> on <BaseTabBarController: 0x7fb49780ea00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I want to show the navigation controller with the **tab bar still visible in the bottom**

Comment: you want to dismiss the imagepicker and present UploadNavigationController

Comment: @Anbu.karthik iam able to dismiss imagepicker, how do i present UploadNavigationController within the UITabBarController

Comment: what was the issue u faced

Comment: @Anbu.karthik added the error message.

Comment: find the topviewcontroller and present your VC

Answer (score 0):

I guess, as you want to show the navigation controller with the tab bar still visible in the bottom, then you should first dismiss image picker then push new controller not present.

Because if you present any controller will cover whole screen as it is presenting from root controller. If you push then it will push from current controller and tabor remains as it was.

```
extension BaseTabBarController : ImagePickerDelegate {

    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        //This is the StoryboardID of Navigationcontroller i want to goto
        let detailVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UploadNavigationController")
        //This is not working
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
        //present(detailVC, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an error "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported"